# Calling InstallShield Custom Action only on minor upgrade from specific version

Tags: .net, installshield, custom-action

I need to call InstallShield (2011) custom action only on minor upgrade from specific version of the product.
For example it should be called during upgrade from 1.1 to 1.4, but not during 1.2 to 1.4, 1.3 to 1.4, etc. This is similar to Upgrade table, but only for minor upgrade. Can you point me, how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built in that I can think of to do this.  That's a very tightly coupled requirement.

My suggestion would be that you fire the custom action during all minor upgrades and then programatically determine whether you should actually do something or not.   When you do something you might leave a bread crumb behind so that it can be the artifact to drive that decision.